# Use Chrome Dev Tools copy from Script

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools

I am creating some helpers scripts in my web app, which I run from the console, to output some information about the current state (e.g. JSON.stringify of objects). For example, I define the temporal `window.Foo` method, I open the Chrome Console, and run `Foo()`. It would be great if I could use the Console method `copy`, which copies some value to the clipboard.

I've checked that if I define a function that uses `copy` inside the Chrome console, it works, but as expected, if I define it in a regular JavaScript file, it doesn't. Do you have any clue how can I access this method through an API or something (if it is even possible)? Any possible workaround to copy info from a script to the clipboard without having to type copy?

The fastest solution is to wrap the script with copy (e.g. `copy(Foo())`), but that means extra typing... I was wondering if it could be done faster.

Thanks

Comment: You can't copy methods , just like sending message to the sockets , you can send whole object but without methods .

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, if you mean exactly this, but maybe it could helps you- look in the `sources` tab :) There you can see all loaded scripts (and also make breakpoints, etc.)